# Making A For Loop Change A Variable Every Time It Runs

Tags: python, string, for-loop, variables

I need to make a python program that takes user input and gives an output like this:

```
Enter Number Here >>> 5
1
 2
  3
   3
    4
     5
```

It needs to add the number of spaces that the number is, so for four, there will be three spaces and then the number four. I'm not sure why but my code does not work. here it is:

```
usernumber = int(input("enter number here >>> "))
spacenum = int(0)
num = int(0)
space = (" ")

for i in range(usernumber):
    
    spacenum + 1
    num + 1
    print(space*spacenum+num)
```

Comment: replace your `+` with `+=` or use something like `spacenum = spacenum + 1`. You're failing to actually assign the result of your addition to back to the variable.

Comment: Why don't you just use ``i``? It's already incrementing.

Comment: hint: forget about the for loop... just write `num = 1234` and then `num + 1` and then `print(num)`, what does it print? 1234 or 1235?

Comment: Why is 3 printed twice?

Answer (score -1):

The `for` loop is already changing variable `i`. Just use it to fit what you need:

```
for i in range(usernumber):
    print(f"{' '*i}{i+1}")
```

Output for usernumber = 5:

```
1
 2
  3
   4
    5
```

Comment: Or avoid the maths in the `print` and do `for i in range(1, usernumber + 1): print(' ' * i, i, sep='')`...

Comment: @JonClements - Wouldn't the first line have 1 space instead of 0 spaces when using your code?

Comment: @not_speshal yeah... but kinda looks like the OPs logic... whether that's intentional or not... *shrugs*

Comment: @JonClements - Agreed. But the output he posted looks like it has 0 spaces on the first line. He can probably adapt as needed!